# nine-fill padding formatting mask for cell phones in Brazil

Tags: excel

In Brazil the cell phone numbers have incremented the nine digit. The first digit is always **9**.

I'd like a formatting mask that shows the new digit if it's not filled in, just like it works with zeros: |Postal code|`00000-000`|.

- Note that I am not looking for a conversion formula.

For example:
The number **123456789** in pseudomask `9 ####-####` should remain **1 2345-6789**,
but the number **12345678** should be **9 1234-5678**.

| real data | showed data | masked |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345678 | 12345678 | 9 1234-5678 |
| 91234567 | 91234567 | 9 9123-4567 |
| 02040608 | 2040608 | 9 0204-0608 |
| 123456789 | 123456789 | 1 2345-6789 |

- Assume that CSV has numbers starting with 0 even though the spreadsheet converts to numerals without zeros.

Comment: This can be done with a simple formula, but "...I am not looking for a conversion formula." ...what are you looking for? What have you tried?

Comment: If you are looking for a custom format that will work for all your possibilities then the question is better suited for SuperUser.com

Answer (score 1):

use the custom formatting of:

```
[<=99999999]9 0000-####;[>99999999]0 0000-####
```

[image]

Comment: I always forget you can do some "conditionals" in the Custom Format, awesome answer!